# password to be given for generating APNS certificate in ios

Tags: passwords, apple-push-notifications

what is the password to be used for generating an APNS certificate in ios. I tried using the password which i have given for authenticating while generating the APNS certioficate. But still I am getting an error saying that 'invalid password'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the password you have to enter when exporting the push certificate to a p12 file, you should give the password of the logged in user on the computer you are using. After you enter that password, you get to choose a password for the p12 file itself.